# Asp.net user control enum flags attribute all except one item?

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums, webforms

I have a enum with flags :

```
[Flags]
public enum Border
{
    Top = 1,
    Bottom = 2,
    Right = 4,
    Left = 8,
    All = 15
}
```

i have a user control by one attribute type of (Border) :

***MyUserControl.ascx***

```
public Border Borders {get;set;}
```

***MyWebForm.aspx***

in my web forms use from myusercontrol such as :

```
<uc1:MyUserControl runat="server" Borders="Top,Bottom,Right"/>
```

how to set Borders attribute All item except one item such as bellow :

```
<uc1:MyUserControl runat="server" Borders="All,~Left"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a new enum value like below

```
[Flags]
public enum Border
{
    Top = 1,
    Bottom = 2,
    Right = 4,
    All_Except_Left = 7,
    Left = 8,
    All = 15
}
```

The idea of flags is that it works bitwise. Every bit represents an enum value. To use combination of values you have to switch on the necessary bits (I think of this as on off switch, hence the term 'switch on'). So your requirement in bit terms it would look like below

```
Top = 0001

Bottom = 0010

Right = 0100

All_Except_Left = 0111

Left = 1000

All = 1111
```

Also have a read through this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx) which would help you understand it better.

Comment: thanks,but i dont want to do this work,in c# for this method very simple use (All & ~Left) , what to do it in aspx user control attribute whitout your method?